# Orchard Core - failed to load resources

Tags: orchardcms

I am trying to create my own theme for Orchard Core based on bootstrap but it fails to load all of the resources, whether it's javascript or styles.

This is my `layout.liquid` view

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="zxx">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Fiction Multipage Bootstrap Template</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="apple-touch-icon.png">
    <!-- Place favicon.ico in the root directory -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="wwwroot/plugins/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- ThemeFisher Icon -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="wwwroot/plugins/themefisher-fonts/themefisher-fonts.css">
    <!-- Light Box -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="wwwroot/plugins/magnific-popup/magnific-popup.css">
    <!-- animation css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="wwwroot/plugins/animate/animate.css">
    <!-- slick slider -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="wwwroot/plugins/slick/slick.css">

    <!-- Revolution Slider -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="wwwroot/css/style.css">

    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map_canvas {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
    </style>
    <script src="wwwroot/plugins/modernizr.min.js"></script>
  </head>

//body here

 <script src="wwwroot/plugins/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="wwwroot/plugins/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- slick slider -->
    <script src="wwwroot/plugins/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
    <!-- filter -->
    <script src="wwwroot/plugins/filterizr/jquery.filterizr.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Lightbox -->
    <script src="wwwroot/plugins/magnific-popup/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Parallax -->
    <script src="wwwroot/plugins/parallax.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Video -->
    <script src="wwwroot/plugins/jquery.vide.js"></script>
    <!-- google map -->
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBu5nZKbeK-WHQ70oqOWo-_4VmwOwKP9YQ"></script>
    <script src="wwwroot/plugins/google-map/gmap.js"></script>

    <script src="wwwroot/js/script.js"></script>
```

My `ResourceManifest` is like so

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using OrchardCore.ResourceManagement;

namespace PakomakTheme
{
    public class ResourceManagementOptionsConfiguration : IConfigureOptions<ResourceManagementOptions>
    {
        private static ResourceManifest _manifest;

        static ResourceManagementOptionsConfiguration()
        {
            _manifest = new ResourceManifest();

            _manifest
                .DefineScript("PakomakTheme-bootstrap-bundle")
                .SetCdn("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js", "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js")
                .SetCdnIntegrity("sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p", "sha384-8fq7CZc5BnER+jVlJI2Jafpbn4A9320TKhNJfYP33nneHep7sUg/OD30x7fK09pS")
                .SetVersion("5.1.3");

            _manifest
                .DefineScript("PakomakTheme")
                .SetUrl("~/wwwroot/js/scripts.min.js", "~/wwwroot/js/scripts.js")
                .SetVersion("7.0.10");

            _manifest
                .DefineStyle("PakomakTheme")
                .SetUrl("~/wwwroot/css/style.min.css", "~/wwwroot/css/style.css")
                // i also tried like so
                //.SetUrl("~/PakomakTheme/wwwroot/css/style.min.css", "~/PakomakTheme/wwwroot/css/style.css")
                .SetVersion("7.0.10");

            _manifest
                .DefineStyle("PakomakTheme-bootstrap-oc")
                .SetDependencies("PakomakTheme")
                .SetUrl("~/Assets/src/scss/bootstrap-oc.min.css", "~/Assets/src/scss/bootstrap-oc.css")
                .SetVersion("1.0.0");
        }

        public void Configure(ResourceManagementOptions options)
        {
            options.ResourceManifests.Add(_manifest);
        }
    }
}
```

and this is what my project hierarchy

[image]

Any ideas what the problem could be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `wwwroot` from your url.
Instead of following

```
.SetUrl("~/wwwroot/js/scripts.min.js", "~/wwwroot/js/scripts.js")
```

Change to

```
 .SetUrl("~/js/scripts.min.js", "~/js/scripts.js")
```